# Error when trying to activate FGLRX graphic propietary control ATI/AMD

Tags: drivers, ati

I'm new to Ubuntu. I still don't understand a lot of features.

As far as I know, I can install the ATI drivers through the `Additional drivers`

When I press 'Activate' in the FGLRX graphic propietary control ATI/AMD it comes up with an error.

> Lo sentimos, la instalación de este controlador falló.
>   Revise el archivo de registro para ver más detalles: /var/log/jockey.log

English translation:

> Sorry, this driver installation failed. Check the log file for more details: /var/log/jockey.log

The problem is that i'm trying to make Compiz work. And since i have no video card drivers i cant modify any of the interface features (Like 3d cube and that stuff).

Comment: What is the output of  /var/log/jockey.log

Comment: @Gastón You might want to check if your hardware is correctly supported by catalyst. You can check on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fglrx#Linux) or following the instructions on [help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

Answer (score 1):

I followed this link:-

[Correct Way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513)

The drivers are working pretty fine after the process. Once you're done with the process run the following command:-

```
fgl_glxgears
```

and you will see something like this:-

[image: A moving 3D object]

To view the graphic card properties use the following command:-

```
fglrxinfo
```

and the output would be something like this :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hy i had the same problem.

```
But you can try to download the orgial driver from ati:
[http://support.amd.com][1]
copy the downloaded file to / or any folder that not contains a " " in path
start a terminal and run the folowing commands:
sudo sh /amd... .run
sudo reboot
```

Couse if you install it from dialog you have to chose the 2. entry and reboot couse the first one is a update.
I did this and if i run the update it comes with the same error as before!
now i have a runing ati driver but it still not work as it should!

I have 2 Monitors and only can use them in Mirror Mode.
If i change this in ATI Catlyst it only closes and does nothing.

In the Monitor Programm it comes with a error like:(try to translate to english)
wasn't able to apply the Monitor Configuration Couse the chosen position/Size for CRTC 147 is over the Limit

(Orginal Text:) Die gewählte Bildschrimkonfiguration konnte nicht angewendet werden Gewählte Position/Größe für CRTC >>147<< ist über dem erlaubtem Limit:Position=(1680,0), Größe=(1680,1050), Maximum=(1920, 1920)

some one know how i remove it couse i found the folowing guid(German):
[GUID](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/ATI/fglrx/Manuelle_Treiberinstallation)

but i cant get in main shell (crtl+alt+F1) couse i don't think it would be good to run this from a gnome session -.- while it uses ati api's :S

Comment: Spaces aren't bad, you just need to break them with "\" or put the location between brackets like "~/Desktop/Folder with spaces/amd.run"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to uninstall the ATI drivers from "Aditional Drivers" Until now those always drivers give me trouble and use the Propietary Drivers instead.

Download them from here: [AMD Graphics](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)

For installing you can open a terminal and type:

```
sudo sh path/to/file/number_of_the_file_x86_amd64.run
```

or just right click->Properties->Allow execute file and double click it.

When the installation finishes you can use

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
```

Then reboot to make sure it runs properly. And when updating the Xserver or anything related with graphics the driver sometimes crashes, so you have to uninstall it, and reinstallit again.

for uninsitall use this

```
sudo amdconfig --uninstall
```

reboot, and you can install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and solved it by installing the driver with the **patch**.

The procedure is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/131027/32413)